# How to send hex character to serial port with C# form app?

Tags: c#, serial-port, format, hex

I want to send the hex over the COM port. I have prepared code manually, but its for string sending.

This is how application looks like currently :

[image: 1]

I need to read data from textbox and then send in hex format to COM port.
Currently I am handling the button click with the following sending code, however currently it is sending hard coded values, but I need ones taken from text field.

```
private void btnSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 if (serialPort1.IsOpen) { 
     dataOUT = tBoxDataOut.Text;
     if (sendWith == "WriteLine") { 
        serialPort1.WriteLine(dataOUT);
     } else if (sendWith == "Write") {
        serialPort1.Write(dataOUT);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: private void btnSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                dataOUT = tBoxDataOut.Text;
                if (sendWith == "WriteLine")
                {
                    serialPort1.WriteLine(dataOUT);
                }
                else if (sendWith == "Write")
                {
                    serialPort1.Write(dataOUT);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: above is function on button send, but its in string format. In need of hex. Thanks in advanced for your support.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, rather than providing extra information in comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "send hex"? Do you mean converting numbers to hex strings, and then sending those strings?

Comment: Trying to recover the question from what author originally wrote, however I am not 100% sure if this is what you meant @NedyalkoPeshev

Comment: canton7 yes that is what I actually want to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about Standard Numeric Format Strings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings). Read the section "The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier".

```
private void btnSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        //dataOUT = tBoxDataOut.Text;
        int intVal = Int32.Parse(tBoxDataOut.Text);
        dataOUT = intVal.ToString("X");
        if (sendWith == "WriteLine")
        {
            serialPort1.WriteLine(dataOUT);
        }
        else if (sendWith == "Write")
        {
            serialPort1.Write(dataOUT);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to include a simple, working example. I do not have a COM port, but the com0com virtual driver works fine for this demonstration; you can download it [here](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). I also used Putty to display the ports' received data; you can download it [here](https://www.putty.org/).

Here's my program:

```
public class HexConvert
{
    SerialPort mySerialPort;

    public HexConvert()
    {
        InitPort();
    }

    void InitPort()
    {
        mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    }

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            string s = "15"; // "F" In Hexadecimal
            int x = Int32.Parse(s);
            string s2 = x.ToString("X");

            if(!mySerialPort.IsOpen)
                mySerialPort.Open();

            mySerialPort.WriteLine(s2);

            mySerialPort.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my com0com utility's Configuration (I added the COM1 and COM2 pair; no other actions taken in this emulator):

[image]

Here is my Putty Configuration (Note that I used COM1 in the program, and COM2 in Putty):

[image]

And, finally, here is the output that my demo app produces:

[image]

Comment: With Parse to int also we have ASCII code of the output. I send 0 digit and really send 30 = ASCII code of 0.

Comment: @NedyalkoPeshev When you constructed serialPort1; did you specify the correct name, baudrate and parity - as in - do they match your windows settings under device manager? You might have to change either, or both. Which program / device are you using to evaluate your output?

Comment: Baudrate is default 9600, Com not selected default. You need to select COM, but settings of program parameters and device manager settings is absolutely same. The main problem I think is with data sending to COM port, because we type in textbox, but need to convert this information to Hex type.

Comment: I do not have serial ports on my PC, so I used the com0com emulator. I also used Putty to display my sent bytes; I'll add my sample code to the answer.

Comment: Look. Just for example. I need to put Hexadecimal values and also need to send them to Serial port, but textbox cant give me a way to send real Hexadecimal values: 40 50 3e fa 55 bf 01 00 2C 04 01 05 1f 04 01. This is what I need to make - send hexadecimal sequence to external module on serial port with C# form app and textbox. If you have any other ideas. Thanks a lot for support.

Comment: That looks like a big number... If you're going to try and fit that into a variable you'll run into trouble; even with the "long" datatype you'll get a handful of Fs at best. You might HAVE to keep this as a string and e.g. send / receive it one character at a time.

Comment: thanks for support.I will try with, but really I need to put 40 50 3e fa 55 bf 01 00 2C 04 01 05 1f 04 01 in textbox and send this to COM(WITHOUT ANY CHANGES). This is the real configuration where I need to send to COM from text box.

Comment: May I ask - what sort of device are you trying to send this to?

Comment: Its device to send different frequency to laser mechanism. The main idea is to send PURE hex command 40 50 3e fa 55 bf 01 00 2C 04 01 05 1f 04 01 to device and device return feedback with string format. Last one is saving final information in Excel table. Second and thirst task i know how to prepare, but i have problem with Hex sending to device for config.